Set Item Description via Data Management API
We use the Data Management API to upload files (items):
Is it possible to set the Description field in the same request or by any other means?
I've tried passing it via endpoint https://aps.autodesk.com/en/docs/data/v2/reference/http/projects-project_id-items-POST/ but the field is never set.
See the image below for the field I'm referring to:
The Description field

Sorry, this feature is still on our wishlist item logged as FDM-3886. Could you share a bit of details on your use cases with us? So that we can pass that on to our engineering team to evaluate the possibilities.
If you don't want to post that publicly, please try to contract aps (dot) help (AT) autodesk (DOT) com.
